# number of non-negative integer solutions for a set of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

How to find the exact number of non-negative integer solutions of the following set of equations :

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6=6 $$
$$ 2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 4$$
$$ x_2 + 2x_4 + x_5 = 4$$
$$ x_3 + x_5 +2x_6 =4$$

Comment: This is counting lattice points in polytopes.  You can google for this beautiful theory.  Concrete instances such as the one you are giving can be solved with the software Latte: http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/

Comment: Could you please provide some motivation for this particular problem. 
I mean this one is a bit smallish, so I do not see what should be the problem about solving this particular one. Even the simplest of all ideas (use 1. to find 0<= xi <=6 and check the 7^6 possibilities by brute force) is perfectly feasible. So if this is not an instance of a general problem or has a clear research motivation it is offtopic. You could ask it on http://math.stackeexchange.com though.

Comment: 7^6 is "smallish" !!!!! anyway i want to solve for n. So, want a general approach 

Comment: It's about 10^5 that's really very smallish (for a computer). But, even to solve it by hand in an ad-hoc way seems feasible (by slightly intelligent brute force). But more immportantly what do you mean by "you want to solve for n"? Is 3n and 2n instead of 6 and 4 (and perhaps n for 2 or not), or n variables, in which form precisely, or still something different. Please formulate a precise question.

Comment: Note that the first equation can be ignored.  It is the sum of the other three, divided by 2.

Comment: Which reduces the problem to 5^3 cases or fewer, and then exploiting symmetry.  Gerhard "Using Intelligent Brute Force Indeed" Paseman, 2013.02.06

Comment: I agree with quid, it's unclear what generalization the OP has in mind.  The specific case can be solved writing $x_2=A+B-C$, $x_3=A-B+C$, and $x_5=-A+B+C$ with $A=2-x_1$, $B=2-x_4$, and $C=2-x_6$.  The non-negativity constraints amount to saying $A,B,C$ are sides of a (possibly degenerate) triangle, each of length no greater than 2, and from this the 15 solutions found by Thomas Kahle are easily obtained.  Even if there's an interesting generalization, it might be better asked at http://math.stackexchange.com as quid advised (but with too many e's in the url).

Comment: To remove any mystery from my previous comment, the $A$, $B$ and $C$ there come from writing the three main equations as $x_2 + x_3 = 2(2-x_1)$, $x_2 + x_5 = 2(2-x_4)$, and $x_3+x_5 = 2(2-x_6)$ and solving these for $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_5$.

Comment: I'm just guessing what the OP has in mind, but if you swap the subscripts for $x_1$ and $x_2$ in my previous comments, there's a fairly obvious generalization.

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be closed, but I'll answer anyway: Here's how to solve your problem using 'zsolve' from 4ti2 (according to the manual www.4ti2.de/4ti2_manual.pdf)

To solve a linear system $Ax = b$ under nonnegativity $x\in\mathbb{N}_0^n$ create a file A.mat with the matrix:

```
4 6
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 2 1 0
0 0 1 0 1 2
```

The first two rows are the dimensions. Then create A.rhs to save the right hand side (as a row vector):

```
1 4
6 4 4 4
```

Finally, create A.sign to encode non-negativity (there are other choices too...)

```
1 6 
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Now run

```
zsolve A
```

Voilà, the file A.zinhom contains your 15 points:

```
15 6

2  0  0  0  4  0
1  0  2  1  2  0
2  0  0  2  0  2
0  4  0  0  0  2
0  3  1  0  1  1
0  2  2  1  0  1
0  2  2  0  2  0
0  1  3  1  1  0
0  0  4  2  0  0
1  1  1  0  3  0
1  0  2  2  0  1
1  1  1  1  1  1
2  0  0  1  2  1
1  2  0  1  0  2
1  2  0  0  2  1
```

Comment: Interesting to see +1. I had heard of that software but to see an example is somehow nice. (If only OP had asked a slightly more general question...) 